# When button calls onClick activity stops

Tags: java, android, onclick

So i have this reset button which calls onclick ResetButtonClicked here is the code

```
public void ResetButtonClicked(View view){
   SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("phone1",sa.toString());
    editor.putString("phone2",re.toString());
    mActivity.stud();
    Toast.makeText(this, "All Emergency Numbers have been Reset.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

BTW: mActivity.stud is a function from main activity.it has been declared before on create code given below

```
 MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
```

Comment: the new operator on a class that extends Activity is never a good idea.

Comment: post your stud function? why you are using stud?

Comment: Without a trace it is hard to tell. Could be a npe on your shared preferences, could be a npe on sa or re, could be a npe on mActivity, could be an issue inside of your stud function.

Comment: From this the only error you will get is maybe your definition of function name in your xml and java code.. i am refering to `public void ResetButtonClicked(View view){}` check if this _ResetButtonClicked_ is the same as the onclick="ResetButtonClicked" in your xml.